# Google Analytics and html feed app

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently launched an app which is basically a html newsfeed of our mobile site. My question is will this affect Google analytics of our mobile site? I have been advised by the developers that it won't affect analytics as it basically works like a browser so will still collect all the data. If it doesn't affect analytics where would this app appear in the list of Browser & OS (or somewhere else)?

Comment: It was built in html by an external company and is available on App Store only, it just feeds our website into the app, it doesn't have a browser config associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

The user agent will be the browser it uses (so Android Webkit Browser if it's a standard android app). OS will be whatever the phone's OS is (Android 4.4).

There really is no difference from using an app browser window to using a full browser. Except it gives you more control on presentation.